# comparing vector of objects to a vector of type int

Tags: c++

my code below takes an array and shuffles it in "random" positions. (i know using rand is not completely random)

I then store the new lists in my vector as shown and repeat this step 1000 times to produce 1000 lists.

I then have another vector of type int which stores the elements, 2,1,5,0,0,4,6,0,3

I would like to compare this vector to each object in my vector of objects to see that number is reproduced.

here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class numbers {
private:
  int indexCount;
  int a;

public:
  void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
  }

  int randomize(int arr[], int n) {
    indexCount = 0;
    int i = n - 1;

    if (n % 2) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);

        indexCount = indexCount + 1;
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);

        i--;
      }
    }

    for (; i > 0; i -= 2) {
      int r = rand() % (i + 1);
      indexCount = indexCount + 1;
      int a = r % (i + 1);
      int b = r / (i + 1);

      swap(&arr[i], &arr[a]);
      swap(&arr[i - 1], &arr[b]);
    }
  }

  void printArray(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << "random calls: " << indexCount << endl;
  }

  inline friend bool operator==(const numbers &ans, const int &str) {
    return ans.a == str;
  }

  inline friend bool operator==(const int &str, const numbers &ans) {
    return str == ans.a;
  }

  bool seqSearch(vector<numbers> list, vector<int> match) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < match.size(); j++) {
        if (list[i] == match[j]) {
          found = true;
        } else {
          found = false;
        }
      }
    }
    cout << found;

    return found;
  }
};

int main() {

  srand(time(NULL));

  vector<numbers> list;
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0};
  int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  numbers num[1000];

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    list.push_back(num[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    list[i].randomize(arr, n);
    list[i].printArray(arr, n);
  }

  numbers a;
  vector<int> match;

  match.push_back(2);
  match.push_back(1);
  match.push_back(5);
  match.push_back(4);
  match.push_back(0);
  match.push_back(0);
  match.push_back(6);
  match.push_back(0);
  match.push_back(3);

  a.seqSearch(list, match);

  return 0;
}
```

I need to check that each element in my vector named match is in the same position as one of the lists generated in my vector of objects.

the problem I am having: my found is always coming up as false.

I tried expanding my search to 10,000 and 100,000 lists and still, my found is false.

any idea how I can see if my vector objects contain the same elements as my vector of ints

Comment: Use `std::equal`.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you try to achieve, so fixing the code to debug it is a problem. Therefore are two things you should fix first `int randomize` requires that it has a return statement at the and which does not exist. But as you don't use the return value anyway, you should change it to `void randomize`. Then you have `swap(&arr[i - 1], &arr[b]);` but the `arr[i - 1]` is out of bounds for `i` being `0`, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why do you implement your own `swap` there is [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)?

Comment: Currently a uni student and wanted us to not use the std swap function

Comment: Asking school/university-related is fine, but you should always mention that. That kind of exercises always have some strange constraints about what should not be used, and that's important to know. E.g.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `operator==` functions you compare against the `numbers::a` field but that field is never initialized. Print out that field for each instance in `seqSearch` and you will see that the field has bogus values.

You probably want to define a constructor for the `numbers` class that initializes that value.

Note that in your code you have multiple definitions of `a` and `indexCount` that shadow each other. This may be part of the problem and should be avoided in general.

Comment: Should i just be initializing it to zero?

Comment: I am not quite clear what your class is supposed to do. What is the purpose of an instance of this class? Why do you even need to store the `indexCount` in an instance? It seems that maybe your class just acts as a namespace here? Why do you have to use `vector<numbers>` and cannot just use `vector<int>`?

Comment: The indexCount is to keep track of how many times the rand() function is called and the vector <numbers> was to store the lists of generated numbers

Comment: But `indexCount` does not apply to *one* single number. It applies to the number of times `rand` was called when shuffling an array that is *completely unrelated* to the instance of `numbers` that was used to shuffle it. Why does a single number have to remember how many times `rand()` was called for shuffling an arbitrary array? My feeling is that you want to do the following: you want to shuffle an array and then create a list from that shuffled array. That is not what your code is doing. Why not just shuffle the array and then create a `vector<int>` from the shuffled array?

Comment: I am following my task description. My question was about comparing a vector to find a match against a vector of objects

Comment: Then you have to define your objects correctly. Like I said, right now, the field `a` that you are using for comparison is never initialized and it is unclear why `randomize` is an instance and not a static function.